# How to pass param from 1 controller to another

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to pass param from the following link in the view of Client controller
and the hash is @client, I want to pass @client.user_id, if i put (:id => @client.user_id) I am not able the get :id in the other controller Estate where I want to pass this param. What should I do ? Is there a way to do it ?(Two controllers are Client and Estate, I want to pass param from Client view to the Estate controllers create method. There is no nesting of resources here!)

```
<%= link_to "New Property", new_estate_path(:key => @client.first.user_id) %>
```

create action

```
def create
    # @estate = Estate.new(params[:estate])
    if current_user.Company.nil?
      @estate = current_user.estates.build(params[:estate])
    else
      serve = User.find(params[:key])
      debugger
      @estate = serve.estates.build(params[:estate])
      #@estate.user_id = user_id
      debugger
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @estate.save
        if @estate.Mgmt.nil?
          EstateMailer.company_confirmation(@estate).deliver
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @estate, notice: 'Estate was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @estate, status: :created, location: @estate }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @estate.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: you want for `new` method or `create` method ?

Comment: does it matter ? I want it for create method

Comment: Yes. `create` is a POST and `new` is a GET. And `link_to` is used in the case of GET actions. In your code, ideally it goes to `new` method and not `create`

Comment: oh k ! i think thats the problem, how can I get it to the create action

Comment: Please see my answer below

Comment: yes you are right! its going to new action, is there any way to pass it direct to create action or through new action ?

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted here should work:

```
<%= link_to "New Property", new_estate_path(:id => @client.user_id) %>
```

I think the problem is, you are expecting the params in `create` method but where as it actually goes to `new` method.

If you are looking for the `create` method. You can do

```
<%= link_to "New Property", estates_path(:id => @client.user_id), :method => :post %>
```

But that is not the right approach to use for `POST` actions. The right solution would be to use `button_to`.

```
<%= button_to "New Property", estates_path(:id => @client.user_id), :method => :post %>
```

`link_to` defaults to `GET` and `button_to` defaults to `POST`, as those are their primary usages. You can override `:method` if you want them to perform other action than their default.

Comment: is there any way that I can pass it through new action? because your its directly submitting the form

Comment: You can't do that through new action.Ideally you should `link_to` `new` action and through new, you submit a form that sends params to `create`. May I know your use case.

Comment: case is kind of difficult to explain, but since now I know the key param is going to new action, so can I pass the param from new to create action ?

Comment: Yes. You can do `render :action => :create` in your new action, that will render `create` as well

Comment: is there anyway that I can just pass the param from new to create ?

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar Why not render?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<%= link_to "New Property", new_estate_path(user_id: @client.user_id) %>
```

In your controller:

```
params[:user_id]
```

You problem is that the `create` action is a `POST` not a `GET`. The `link_to` will only allow `GET` actions.

Comment: u mean key: @client.user_id ?

Comment: but when I put debugger in the controller to check value, it shows nil

Comment: edited the answer :) you issue is with the `create` action who is a POST request. You usually hit this method with a html `form`

Answer (score 0):

I made class variable in the controller outside all the actions.
@@key, and in the new action assigned @@key the user_id that was coming through the params, and this @@key in the create action. I don't know if its the right way to do it. But it worked like a charm !